# Collapsable Drop Down List Box in HTML

Tags: html, css

Is there any sort of free control which does what the Occupation field does on http://monster.ca?  That is allow for grouping of the options in a drop down box with expandable sections?  I just learned about the [optgroup tag](http://www.braintrove.com/article/18) which is close to what I want, but not quite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with a traditional <select> control, and I doubt there are ready-made components that fit the bill. If you do want to make this yourself, and don't want to buy into a toolkit like extjs or dojo (which would probably make it easiest to build this), I can recommend the following tree library, as it is very simple to use and BSD licensed: http://www.silverstripe.com/tree-control/

Comment: That is nifty looking, I will give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a mock up of a drop down control.
The down arrow is an image, all the remainder is made of divs, the drop down list itself being a big div with overflow containing lot of controls with JavaScript to manage all of this (like collapsing sections).

So you can do that yourself, with a bit of work, and lot of help from a good JavaScript framework...

Comment: Just to add, because of that it looks like Windows XP even if you're running Vista. They'd been better of using their own drop down image :)

Comment: I am on XP, so I didn't notice... It is probably worse on other systems! :-D

Answer (score 1):

Basically what the developers at Monster.ca are doing, is emulating a select-control using a  div-element with scrollable content.

Take a look at the ["overflow" CSS-property](http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure if the interface is any good for your purposes:

http://flooble.com/scripts/hier.php